# iTextSharp Storing barcodes as Elements - Null reference exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, itext, barcode

Im working on a class that will render PDF documents on an intranet web server.  The problem that I am having is that iTextSharp uses the PDFWriter to render the barcode images and I am trying to build a collection of IElements before I render the document.  Is there a way to create a collection that incorporates barcode images or is there a better way to code this class?

Hopefully my code can explain it better.  Thanks.

```
public class PDFDoc
{

    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }
    private List<IElement> Elements { get; set;}
    ...
    private MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    private Document doc = new Document();
    private PdfWriter writer;

    private void initializeDocument()
    {
        doc = new Document(new Rectangle(Width, Height), marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom);
        writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        Elements = new List<IElement>();
    }

    private FileStreamResult GenerateLabel(IEnumerable<IElement> elements)
    {
        doc.Open();
        foreach (var e in elements)
        {
            doc.Add(e);
        }
        //doc.Add(GenerateBarcodeImage("123456"));  //GenBC works here but not below
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        doc.Close();

        byte[] byteinfo = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Write(byteinfo, 0, byteinfo.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }

    private Image GenerateBarcodeImage(string code)
    {
        Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
        code128.Code = code;
        code128.X = 1f;
        return code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(new PdfContentByte(writer), null, null);
    }

//Program
        public FileStreamResult RenderLabel()
    {
        Elements.Add(new Paragraph("This is a test"));
        Elements.Add(GenerateBarcodeImage("123456"));  //This gives a null ref exception.
        return GenerateLabel(Elements); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code snippet is that you're trying to access the `MemoryStream` after calling `Document.Close()`. You can move the `Close()` call below you call `ms.ToArray()`, or do away with the `MemoryStream` entirely.

When you instantiate a `PdfWriter`, you can use **any** available `Stream`, so why not use `Response.OutputStream`:

```
List<IElement> Elements  = new List<IElement>();     
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
    document, Response.OutputStream
  );
  document.Open();
  PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
    code128.Code = "code " + i.ToString();
    Elements.Add(code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Count; ++i) {
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Barcode: " + i.ToString()));
    document.Add(Elements[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  After reading through your code I realized that my problem wasn't that the Closed() had been called but rather that Open() had not been called.  I moved doc.Open(); to the initializeDocument() method and it is working properly.  I'm using a memorystream to work with the FileStreamResult in MVC.